# BLE background scanning on Android 10+ Ionic 4

Tags: typescript, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic4, ionic-native, background-mode

I'm using *Ionic Framework*, *Angular* and *Typescript* to scan for *BLE devices*. I'm doing a scan every 3 minutes and waiting for 1 minute before each scan.

I'm using the Background Mode plugin, BLE plugin, PowerManagement plugin, Geolocation plugin from Ionic native.

The app works perfectly while scanning in Foreground mode.

When I try to scan in Background mode the app works only on some devices, it doesn't scan on Samsung, OnePlus, and some Redmi devices.

The BLE.startscan([]) is never called in Background mode. How can I fix that?

I don't see any errors using logcat.

I added the new permissions for Bluetoth - BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT and BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE

I'm stuck. I will be really grateful if someone can help me.

Thank you

Comment: Could this just be an energy saving restriction from the OS? Maybe try changing the settings in Settings -> Apps -> <your app> -> battery to "not optimized"

Comment: the background mode plugin has an option where it disables the battery optimization
this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
      this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
      this.backgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations();
      console.log('background activated !!!!');
    });

Comment: Maybe this option doesn't work on all devices. Have you compared the OS settings between the working and not working devices?

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from the energy saving restrictions. I change the battery optimization settings manually and I still can't scan in background
I'm also using PowerOptimization plugin from Ionic to request for battery optimization

Comment: Thanks for checking anyway! :)

Comment: Is it possible that the Background Mode plugin and the BLE plugin are incompatible?

Comment: You need to use a foreground service, because "Android versions 8+ restrict services from running in the background to only 10 minutes after an app leaves the foreground. This blocks background beacon detections.
By default on Android 8+, the library will use the JobScheduler to run scans, but these are limited to at most every 15 minutes. For use cases where apps need frequent beacon scanning in the background, a foreground service is a viable alternative." from [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html). (

Comment: The problem was in the Background Mode plugin. It's not updated to work with the latest Android versions. 
Using this plugin -> https://bitbucket.org/TheBosZ/cordova-plugin-run-in-background/src/master/  now I'm able to scan in background for BLE devices